# How can I preserve custom OSX "open with" setting on vim save

Tags: django, macos, vim, macvim

When I save files with MacVim 7.3, any custom "open with" setting for the file is replaced with the default for files with that suffix.

I'm working on some (django-templated) html files in OS X 10.6.  They have a file suffix of '.html'.  If I open them by double-clicking in the finder, they are opened by my web browser by default.  I want to continue having this be the default behavior for .html files.

But I would like html files I'm currently *developing* to open with MacVim by default.  This is seemingly easy, I can set a custom "open with" setting for any of these files from the file info panel in the finder.  The problem is that when I save one so customized, MacVim doesn't preserve the setting.  The file info panel will show the "open with" setting is back to the default for .html files.

The Mac TextEdit app seems to preserve this custom setting on save, but MacVim doesn't.  Does anyone know a trick to make this work?  Is this likely a bug in MacVim, or in my vim config?

I do not want change the file extension to something other than .html, or the default app for opening .html files. I just want to figure out how to preserve my custom setting if it's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:set bkc=yes
```